# How to restore hidden Library folder in Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, restore

I want to restore the hidden user Library folder from Time Machine but I am unable to see it when I enter Time Machine. Read on.

I thought the hidden Library folder would appear if I used the Terminal command to **either** reveal the hidden Library folder **AND/OR** to show all hidden files and folders. Both commands work outside of Time Machine but they don't show any hidden files or folders when I am in Time Machine space.

Is it possible to see and/or restore the hidden Library folder in Time Machine?

I appreciate any help? I'm stuck.

P.S. I am using 10.8.1 if that is helpful to know. And the Time Machine backup that I am trying to restore my Library folder from was from my previous hard drive in which I was also running 10.8.1. I switched to a new hard drive.

Comment: Which Terminal Commands have you used?

Comment: In Terminal you can open any location by typing `open /Users/username/Library` and start TimeMachine from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the Finder's menu "goto" while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the library folder is visible in the menu:

[image: Finder with Library Folder in Goto Menu]

Select it. The finder shows the content of `/Users/<your name>/Library`. Now start Time Machine by clicking on its icon in the dock – violà, you have what you want:

[image: Time Machine showing User Library folder]

When you want to access another invisible folder that is not listed in the 'Go' list in Finder you can go to the same folder and choose for 'Go to Folder' or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Here you can type in any location you want to goto.

[image: Go to Folder]

Comment: vilmoskörte I want to kiss you right now. I used your advice and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I tried using Tinker Tool and it does show the hidden Library folder but the folder has the red dot with the dash inside meaning I don't have access to it. So although a creative solution I am not able to access the contents of the Library folder.

I used these Terminal commands:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
killall Finder
```

Both methods show hidden files and folders but they don't work right for Time Machine.

Comment: +1 This worked great when I needed to restore a backup of my `~/.profile`. Remember you can change back by running the same `defaults` command again, with `false` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bypass` to make changes in the folders for snapshots: `sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Helpers/bypass chflags nohidden /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/*/*/Users/*/Library/`. `bypass` was in `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/MacOS/bypass` on Lion.

Related questions:

- [Scripting the unhiding of Library folders on Time Machine disks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61259/scripting-the-unhiding-of-library-folders-on-time-machine-disks)
- [How to recover file from 'hidden' directory with Time Machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/322497/how-to-recover-file-from-hidden-directory-with-time-machine)

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me nuts because I was trying to restore files from the a TM user Library folder using the "Browse Other Backup Disks" command for TM.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Tinker Tool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) 4.9 I showed invisibles, then went into Time Machine.  Invisibles were still there.